# java- how to wait constantly for an event to happen

Tags: java

I am creating an application in which there are multiple stages- for each stage a message is sent to my queue in Amazon Simple Work Flow (SWF)... The app should start a new thread for each message that is received.

How do I implement the waiting part- so that the application constantly scans the queue for new messages and takes action the moment a message is received?

Answer (score 3):

`BlockingQueue` and its implementation `LinkedBlockingQueue` can be useful here.

When `Thread` will want to `take` something from queue by calling

```
queue.take()
```

and queue will be empty, such thread will wait until other thread will put something into queue by calling

```
queue.put(something).
```

Also if queue is full, `queue.put()` will make putting thread wait until there will be room in queue for new elements.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask about is called a Producer-Consumer model
you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

The basic idea: the site is a producer and you are as a client a consumer.

you wait() until the listener receive a message and then notifAll()

```
    class WaitForAmazon{
    private boolean available = false;
    private int contents;

    public synchronized int consumer() {
        while (available == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return contents;
    }

    public synchronized void producer(int value) {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        contents = value;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: my application is a web app- it acts as both the producer and consumer- is your answer still applicable to my scenario? Thanks...

Comment: absolutely. it is a model applicable for any server-client scenario. the consumer is the client, it should wait for an event that happens on your machine (for instance, another piece of the code performs contents++; available = true;)

Comment: +1 for the example.  I'd make `contents` a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue to handle a rush of messages, but only once it's working properly as is.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is `poll` the `queue` until you get a new message in a `while loop` mechanism.once you get the new message , you can invoke your own action.

Comment: Polling is a rather ugly way of doing this, IMO.  A blocking solution would be better, assuming the app isn't constantly busy (ie: that you're not getting a message with every poll).

Comment: @cHao, there are many applications still use polling technique effectively though I admit there are some drawbacks in it.

Comment: @UnniVMana my application may get as many as 50+ messages every second- is polling a good solution to my scenario? Is there any upper limit (i.e. max number of messages received per second) beyond which polling is not effective/useful? Thanks...

Comment: @Arvind: Depending on the code, sometimes polling can be *better* with a high load -- it means more chance that each poll will give you something to process, so you're not wasting time.  But 50 hits a second is not much; unless you insert a delay between each check of the queue, you'll be spending more CPU time looking for messages than you will actually processing them.

Comment: @cHao, This is pure design issue and can be implemented using diff techniques.one way is when new messages are inserted into the queue, you can maintain a log file of the newly inserted messages and check for it(or may be something like that).This will avoid polling the queues directly.I have come across one FileMonitor example using polling implementation. http://geosoft.no/software/filemonitor/FileMonitor.java.html(only for reference). Also, what I feel is go for solutions that are implemented using standard framework such as Spring etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a serversocket:

[serversocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

in particular, the .accept() method waits for someone to require a connection. You could then instantiate a new thread passing the parameters needed to mantain the connection (address, port, etc).