# basic java server/framework to check constantly for an event to happen

Tags: java, frameworks, server

I have a simple JAVA server program thats is constantly checking a queue, and when a message arrives, it just proccess it.

It's very basic, tiny and robust and I basically monitor if it's functioning properly by checking the logs and using some 'ping messages' that give me an OK answer.

I have to do some improvements in this program (add some new functionalities), and was wondering what would be the best aproach to re-do this kind of server, using some (free) server or framework, taking advantage of better monitoring tools. As it's very tiny, code would be dead-easy to port anywhere.

For example, I don't think a Tomcat is necessary for this usage, but would like to know if there are any interesting/recommended alternatives.

I've searched other threads on this topic, but answers given don't mention any kind of server nor framework, for example:

[java- how to wait constantly for an event to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879562/java-how-to-wait-constantly-for-an-event-to-happen)